# SQL syntax error when creating a stored procedure in MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a hard time locating an error when trying to create a stored procedure in mysql.

If I run every single line of the procedure independently, everything works just fine.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE cms_proc_add_child 
(
    param_parent_id INT, param_name CHAR(255),
    param_content_type CHAR(255)
)
BEGIN
    SELECT @child_left := rgt FROM cms_tree WHERE id = param_parent_id;
    UPDATE cms_tree SET rgt = rgt+2 WHERE rgt >= @child_left;
    UPDATE cms_tree SET lft = lft+2 WHERE lft >= @child_left;
    INSERT INTO cms_tree (name, lft, rgt, content_type) VALUES 
    (
        param_name,
        @child_left,
        @child_left+1,
        param_content_type
    );
END
```

I get the following (helpful) error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

I just don't know where to start debugging, as every single one of these lines is correct.

Do you have any tips?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

As line 3 contains the first `;` perhaps you have a problem with your delimiters.

See [http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/stored-programs-defining.html](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html)

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE dorepeat(p1 INT)
BEGIN
    SET @x = 0;
    REPEAT SET @x = @x + 1; UNTIL @x > p1 END REPEAT;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 4):

Thanks, ***near '' at line 3*** was my problem and the delimiter statement fixed it!  I always want things to make sense and this does.  As the '' indicates it's at the end of the procedure, but no END statement was found thus the syntax error.  And I wondered why I kept seeing a lot of people using the delimiter statement. I see the light!

Answer (score 1):

You never declare your @child_left variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you having issues with a bunch of Procedure that can't run at the same time but can run successfully alone, Try separate them with `Go` command.

Ex:

```
--i)
CREATE PROCEDURE A
AS
BEGIN
END;
GO 

--ii)
CREATE PROCEDURE B
AS
BEGIN
END;
```