# Is declare in mysql giving syntax error?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm new to mysql and I'm trying to create a stored procedure but getting syntax error due to declare a variable.
The version of mysql I'm using is 5.5.43 and my procedure is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spSearch
(
    p_ACTION INT,
    p_PROJECT_CUSTOMER INT,     
    p_PROJECT_NAME VARCHAR(50), 
    p_PROJECT_SALESPERSON INT, 
    p_PROJECT_MANAGER INT,
    p_PROJECT_PMF INT,
    p_PROJECT_TYPE INT,
    p_PROJECT_DESIGNER INT,
    p_PROJECT_AANDD INT,
    p_PROJECT_REFD INT,
    p_PROJECT_VENDOR INT,
    p_PROJECT_GENERALCONTRACTOR INT,
    p_PROJECT_PUNCHLIST varchar(1),
    p_PROJECT_LOCATION INT,
    p_PROJECT_CLIENTTYPE INT,
    p_PROJECT_INSTALLDATE VARCHAR(50),
    p_PROJECT_INSTALLDATETO VARCHAR(50),
    p_PROJECT_ORDERENTRYDATE VARCHAR(50),
    p_PROJECT_ORDERENTRYDATETO VARCHAR(50),
    p_PROJECT_MOVEINDATE VARCHAR(50),
    p_PROJECT_MOVEINDATETO VARCHAR(50),
    p_PROJECT_ACTIVE_FLAG VARCHAR(1)
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE ABC VARCHAR(1400);
END;
```

I'm getting this error:

```
 #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 28
```

Please help to remove this syntax error.

Comment: Are you sure that you show us all code of procedure?

Comment: To find the error, I'm testing the procedure only with this part (that I have shown to you) and found that declare causes syntax error.

Comment: But error says `near '@ABC =1'` I do not see that code in your procedure

Comment: Oh... Sorry for that. I have updated the error now.

Comment: Possible dublicate of [SQL syntax error when creating a stored procedure in MYSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/639089/4275342)

Comment: Or [MySQL server stored procedure syntax error](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19062150/4275342)

Comment: Also [Mysql syntax error creating stored procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23160044/4275342)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have a problem with your delimiters. try this:

```
delimiter //

CREATE PROCEDURE spSearch
(
    p_ACTION INT,
    p_PROJECT_CUSTOMER INT,     
    p_PROJECT_NAME VARCHAR(50), 
    p_PROJECT_SALESPERSON INT, 
    p_PROJECT_MANAGER INT,
    p_PROJECT_PMF INT,
    p_PROJECT_TYPE INT,
    p_PROJECT_DESIGNER INT,
    p_PROJECT_AANDD INT,
    p_PROJECT_REFD INT,
    p_PROJECT_VENDOR INT,
    p_PROJECT_GENERALCONTRACTOR INT,
    p_PROJECT_PUNCHLIST varchar(1),
    p_PROJECT_LOCATION INT,
    p_PROJECT_CLIENTTYPE INT,
    p_PROJECT_INSTALLDATE VARCHAR(50),
    p_PROJECT_INSTALLDATETO VARCHAR(50),
    p_PROJECT_ORDERENTRYDATE VARCHAR(50),
    p_PROJECT_ORDERENTRYDATETO VARCHAR(50),
    p_PROJECT_MOVEINDATE VARCHAR(50),
    p_PROJECT_MOVEINDATETO VARCHAR(50),
    p_PROJECT_ACTIVE_FLAG VARCHAR(1)
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE ABC VARCHAR(1400);
END//

delimiter ;
```

Comment: Glad to have been of help