# Procedure breaking when trying to import into DB

Tags: mysql, database, xampp, mysql-workbench, mariadb

I have the following procedure that when I manually import this is breaking for some unknown reason.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `register_house`(  
 IN UID CHAR(17),
 IN new_username VARCHAR(16),
 IN new_signature CHAR(64),
 IN email VARCHAR(128),
 IN postcode VARCHAR(16),
 IN customer_name VARCHAR(45),
 IN phone_number VARCHAR(16)
)
BEGIN
UPDATE bb.checkin SET username = new_username, signature = new_signature WHERE _site = UID;
END
```

I'm getting the following error in Mysql Workbench -

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 11
```

Can someone suggest what the problem is?

#### UPDATE

As suggested i've amended to include the DELIMITER and now get the following error:

```
 Error Code: 1728. Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted
```

The tables all appear to look correct is the way to 'de-corrupt' them if they have corrupted somehow?

Comment: delimeters are missing in your procedure like $$...

Comment: After the END command? I tried adding $$ and still no joy :(

Comment: Not only $$ at the `END` (pun intended). Have you also set `DELIMITER $$` before `CREATE PROCEDURE`?

Answer (score 1):

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/639356/2381157, try this

```
delimiter //

CREATE PROCEDURE `register_house2`(  
 IN UID CHAR(17),
 IN new_username VARCHAR(16),
 IN new_signature CHAR(64),
 IN email VARCHAR(128),
 IN postcode VARCHAR(16),
 IN customer_name VARCHAR(45),
 IN phone_number VARCHAR(16)
)
BEGIN
UPDATE bb.checkin SET username = new_username, signature = new_signature WHERE _site = UID;
END
//

delimiter ;
```

It worked for me in MySQL 5.5

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me...

Added this to the start of the statement on line 1;

```
DELIMITER $$
```

then on the ver

```
END $$
```

Then finally to fix the 'corrupted' message I simply ran the following file:

```
C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql_upgrade.exe
```